# How can I use ExecuteDelete for a collection of Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to use bulk delete feature of ef core 7. I know we can give id and use executeDelete() like this `_context.Set<T>().Where(t=>t.Id == id).ExecuteDeleteAsync()`.

But what if I want to delete a collection of entities? How can I complete this method?

```
public async Task BulkDeleteAsync(ICollection<T> entities)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>()......ExeuteDeleteAsync();

    }
```

Should I use `where`? How?

Answer (score 0):

Depended on number of entities you can try using collection of ids (there can be limit on number of parameters to be passed depended on the database provider):

```cs
var ids = entities.Select(e => e.Id)
    .ToList();

await _context.Set<T>()
   .Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id))
   .ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```